# Why is Redefining a Key in a Dictionary Literal Allowed

Tags: javascript, python, json, dictionary, literals

In Python, Javascript, JSON (and probably other languages too) you are allowed to redefine a key in a dictionary literal like so:

```
{ "foo" : 1, "foo" : 2 }
```

This seems like it would lead to unpredictable results, and I can't imagine why a person would ever do this intentionally. Is there any good reason that this is allowed?

Comment: Perhaps it's because the dictionary is in the process of being created, so looking up every key seen to see if it already exists would slow thing too much.

Comment: Simplicity and consistency. Changing a key/value is allowed in general and the order is well-defined in the case of a literal. It makes it possible to more easily and naturally write code that generates, say, JSON from disparate sources.

Comment: There are probably good reasons but maybe you should rephrase your question as to whether it would be possible or desirable to detect duplicates and what kinds of errors it would make sense to throw in that case. For example, this is probably outside the scope of the CF grammar (the parser) and as others have said, you would have to build a hash table to detect duplicates, so this is not done for you.

Comment: Also just because you can't think of why a person would do this doesn't mean someone else couldn't think of a useful way to generate JavaScript or JSON code that worked this way, to take advantage of this, for example to serialize the state of a changing system as changes come in, and then parse and run the JSON and get back the most recent state at some point in the future.

Comment: As an aside, JSON isn't a language.

Comment: I'm surprised by the negativity on this question. 
@martineau: how would there be any performance penalty? Replacing a dictionary value seems to have equal performance than inserting a value and raising an exception if one already exists.

Comment: @pvg Even though many languages may define this operation, the result is anything but obvious, as key-value pairs in an associative array are not ordered, thus it seems inconsistent to rely on the order of their construction.

Comment: @JaredUpdike I'm not sure I understand your complaint. I did ask why any person would want to do this.

Comment: @speedplane: They might about equal in an existing dictionary, but my point was that there _isn't one_ yet.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I get it, but I still don't see how that can help make it faster. In fact, if the interpreter or runtime could assume that all keys were unique, I believe it could use that assumption to make dictionary creation faster, not the other way around.

Comment: @speedplane: It would make it faster because, if a dictionary already existed, it could quickly check to see if each subsequent key already existed—unfortunately there isn't one already so some other mechanism would have to be used, which would almost certainly entail more overhead than not checking.

Comment: @speedplane the _contents_ of a dictionary is perfectly well defined after an ordered sequence of insert operations. it's pretty intuitive what contents you end up with after the inserts are performed in the order written in the literal.

Comment: @pvg I would disagree that the order of the declaration is intuitive. An ordered sequence of insert operations is procedural in nature, i.e., one step clearly follows the next, so there is no question as to what comes first. A dictionary literal on the other hand, is declarative in nature, and is declaring an unordered set of keys. IMHO, it's far from intuitive that an unordered set would be declared in an ordered manner.

Comment: @speedplane I think stating in the question "I can't imagine" feels like an argument from ignorance and a bad habit to cultivate, as well as a bad way to ask a question; you are already framing it as unanswerable. I'm glad you asked this question because the answers and comments have been enlightening. Also re:@pvg there are purely functional languages (Haskell's Data.Map) with insertion semantics where the fromList insertions have to happen in some order, so "last wins" makes sense -- even when each insertion creates a new Map (persistent data structures). (It is recursive, not imperative.)

Comment: @speedplane I agree that there is negativity toward this question, but you have been given comments about the question and have not updated or rewritten the question to more closely align with Stack Overflow's on-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask approach. I also feel that SO was friendlier and discussion-ier in its earlier days but to scale to more questions they had to make cut offs and teaching users to ask answerable questions was one conscious choice they made.

Comment: @speedplane regarding efficiency, if the compiler or parser had to build the entire hash in memory as it was parsing, imagine it parsing a massive JSON file, say, 20 GB of log files, just to detect duplicates -- you would not expect the parser to use so much RAM (or crash), but deferring this same process to runtime makes sense (instead of doing it twice). Memory usage performance/efficiency is another kind of performance/efficiency consideration.

Comment: @JaredUpdike I see your point, but I'm a bit dubious. I don't claim to know the exact details of Python's semi-compilation step (or the various Javascript JITs), but I imagine it already does the work of converting literals from text to some more concise internal representation. I'd bet that parsing the 20GB literal already takes a proportional amount of RAM and I doubt that there would be any real performance degradation to check  for dups. That said, I do see your point.

Answer (score 2):

It won't lead to unpredectable result. The last key will have its value in the object.

```
var o = { "foo" : 1, "foo" : 2 };
```

is pretty much the same as:

```
var o = {};
o["foo"] = 1;
o["foo"] = 2; // overrides the previous ones
// o == {"foo": 2}
```

Comment: I don't see those two as the same. The keys of an associative array are unordered, so it's not obvious what is happening. The second is entirely obvious.

Comment: @speedplane When the interpretter is parsing (left-to-right), I think it would assign key-value pairs as it interpret them, so the two are **pretty much** the same!

Comment: That relies on your understanding of how the interpreter parses the code, it makes less sense from the language perspective.

Comment: @speedplane: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) specifies that key/datum pairs  "are evaluated from left to right to define the entries of the dictionary", so the two snippets _do_ pretty much accomplish the same thing. I still don't consider this really an answer to your question, however, only the assertion about unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I get that this is defined behavior. When I say "unpredictable", I mean the user will have a hard time predicting it... i.e., a non-obvious result. My point is that it seems wrong, and I don't see any good reason for allowing it.

Comment: Since it's specified as left-to-right, one can assume the last one seen will be the one that "sticks"—so the result is completely predictable. You can't seem to accept that it's allowed because not allowing it would not only be slower, in some cases it would actually be undesirable.

Comment: @martineau The problem is that there is no idea of order with respect to the keys of an associative array, so grafting order on to associative array literals is not terribly intuitive.

Comment: @speedplane: The order of the keys in the mapping are irrelevant. We discussing the building of one from a text literal which most definitely has an order. I grow weary of this conversation—so let's allow it to end,

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects essentially map to associative arrays which have the functionality of adding, deleting, and reassigning key value stores.

If an object has the ability to reassign a value, why would it prevent you the ability of doing so? There are many different ways to define an object in Javascript and I'd imagine the overhead to restricting operations based on syntax would be insane and would provide very little (IMO no) value.